# Need help - How to loop through a list and/or a map

Tags: scala, list, loops, foreach, gatling

Scala is pretty new for me and I have problems as soon as a leave the gatling dsl.

In my case I call an API (Mailhog) which responds with a lot of mails in json-format. I can’t grab all the values. 
I need it with “jsonPath” and I need to “regex” as well. 
That leads into a map and a list which I need to iterate through and save each value.

```
.check(jsonPath("$[*]").ofType[Map[String,Any]].findAll.saveAs("id_map"))
.check(regex("href=3D\\\\\"(.*?)\\\\\"").findAll.saveAs("url_list"))
```

At first I wanted to loop the “checks” but I did’nt find any to repeat them without repeating the “get”-request too. So it’s a map and a list.

1) I need every value of the map and was able to solve the problem with the following foreach loop.

```
.foreach("${id_map}", "idx") {
    exec(session => {
        val idMap = session("idx").as[Map[String,Any]]
        val ID = idMap("ID")
        session.set("ID", ID)
    })
    .exec(http("Test")
        .get("/{ID}"))
    })}
```

2) I need every 3rd value of the list and make a get-request on them. Before I can do this, I need to replace a part of the string. I tried to replace parts of the string while checking for them. But it won’t work with findAll.

```
.check(regex("href=3D\\\\\"(.*?)\\\\\"").findAll.transform(raw => raw.replace("""=\r\n""","")).saveAs("url"))
```

How can I replace a part of every string in my list? 
 also how can I make a get-request on every 3rd element in the list.

I can't get it to work with the same foreach structure above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was abole to solve the problem by myself. At first I made a little change to my check(regex ...) part.

```
.check(regex("href=3D\\\\\"(.*?)\\\\\"").findAll.transform(_.map(raw => raw.replace("""=\r\n""",""))).saveAs("url_list"))
```

Then I wanted to make a Get-Request only on every third element of my list (because the URLs I extracted appeared three times per Mail).

```
.exec(session => {
    val url_list = 
    session("url_list").as[List[Any]].grouped(3).map(_.head).toList
            session.set("url_list", url_list)
})
```

At the end I iterate through my final list with a foreach-loop.

```
foreach("${url_list}", "urls") {

    exec(http("Activate User")
        .get("${urls}")
    )
}
```